# Set repeatInterval in local notification

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker, uilocalnotification, repeat

I want to set repeat interval to the value which user selects from date picker.I have date picker of type countdown mode in my application.If user selects 4 hours 15 minutes from date picker then I am setting firedate using the following code and alarm rings.

```
 [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[pickerTimer countDownDuration]]
```

But I want that notification should repeat after every 4 hours 15 minutes until user cancels it. I have done r&d searched a lot but I can not figure out.The code  I have used so far is:

```
localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
[localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[pickerTimer countDownDuration]]]; 

if(localNotification.fireDate){

    [self _showAlert:@"Time is scheduled" withTitle:@"Daily Achiever"];
}
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];


localNotification.alertBody=@"alaram";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[localNotification setAlertAction:@"View"];
[localNotification setRepeatInterval:[pickerTimer countDownDuration]];

//The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
// [localNotification setAlertBody:[alertBodyField text]]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
//[localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
[localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]]; //Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1

  localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

localNotification.repeatInterval=NSHourCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system

//[alertNotification setHidden:NO]; //Set the alertNotification to be shown showing the user that the application has registered the local notification
```

Please help me to solve. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: hey congrats that you've solved your problem. if you don't mind can you share your solution as i am facing the same situation i want to repeat the local notification twice in a day like morning and evening daily so unable to figure out how to do so please if you can help me with some code

Answer (score 1):

We cannot set custom Value for `repeatInterval` in the `UILocalNotification`.

The simplest way you can achieve this by creating a new `localNotification`  every 4.25 hours and copy the notification details of the the the existing one and delete it  while handling the local notification.

Other way is to change the `firedate` while handling the local notification.

Comment: I have solved it by setting new fire date when receive local notification is called . I have used following code for that:          - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    testDate=notif.fireDate;
    NSLog(@"DATE IS%@",testDate);
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
    [self playSoundWithNotification:notif];
   
    
    [self _showAlert:@"Alaram" withTitle:@"Daily Achiever"];
}

Comment: if application is in background than how to schedule notification again ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem using following code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

testDate=notif.fireDate;
NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
[self playSoundWithNotification:notif];
[self _showAlert:@"Alaram" withTitle:@"Daily Achiever"];
 }


-(void)_showAlert:(NSString*)pushmessage withTitle:(NSString*)title
{

UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:pushmessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertView show];

if (alertView) {
    FocusViewController *fvc=[[FocusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FocusViewController" bundle:nil];

    [fvc insert:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:refTimeIntrval sinceDate:testDate]];

}}
```

Here testDate and refTimeInterval are variables declared in .pch file.