# How to set UINotification for specific days like every Monday and Friday?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am writing an alarm app. In the app, user can select days from the picker for setting alarm on that day with time. But I don't know to set alarm (`UILocalNotification`) for specific day in a week `(0 - 7)`.

I just wanted to set fire date of `UILocalNotification` on specific day like ex. **Monday, Friday and Sunday..**

I have searched on net and got many similar forums but none of them worked for me.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769462/set-repeatinterval-in-local-notification visit this link

Answer (score 1):

Set the local notification `fireDate` for the first notification that should be made. Then set the `repeatInterval` for the duration between any notification and the next notification.

Comment: can be more specific please? didn't get you !

Comment: Ok got it.. But what if user selects Monday, Tuesday, Thursday and Sunday ? how would you calculate `repeatInterval` then ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you have included codes which you have tried.
Anyways,

```
NSDate myOwnDate; // myOwnDate can be a date that is on a specific day. Make sure it is a valid date variable

UILocalNotification* local_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[local_notification setFireDate:myOwnDate]; 
[local_notification setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
[local_notification setAlertBody: @"Your alarm is ringing!"];

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:local_notification];
```

Pretty straightforward I would say.

Comment: I could have more than one date ! how set that ?

Comment: You will need multiple local notifications then.

Comment: You mean do I have to create two separate notifications ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Local notifications have only 1 fire date, hence you need more than one instance.

Comment: But what if user selects Monday, Tuesday, Thursday and Sunday ? Than I  have to create 4 notifications ? I don't think thats a good idea...

Comment: You don't have another choice, local notifications don't offer you arbitrary repeat specification.