# Repeat UILocalNotification on Specific day

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, datepicker, localnotification

I need to set UILocalNotification, I just need to take hour and minute from DatePicker and need to set specific date  *( like : Monday )* and repeat it on every Monday.

I have two question about it :

First one ; is it possible to show only "day names" like "Sunday"  on the date section of  date picker?

Second question is ; what is the correct codes if i want to set specific date for local notification ?

Thank you for the answers and here is my code below ;

```
-(IBAction) alarmButton:(id)sender {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePickerSet1.date];
NSLog ( @"Alarm Set :%@" , dateTimeString);

[self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate1: dateTimePickerSet1.date];

}

-(void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate1:(NSDate *)fireDate {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

notification.fireDate = fireDate;
notification.alertBody = @"Alarm Set !";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: Check  - http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html 
or you can also get some help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769462/set-repeatinterval-in-local-notification or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014438/repeating-a-local-notification-after-every-14-daystwo-weeks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1 =>** I can not understand what you want. *(But if you want to display only name of days such like **sunday, monday,....to saturday** then use [**UIPickerView.**](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.in/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html))*

**Question 2 =>** ***YES*** you can get correct date of specific day and you can get notification on every *specific day* by set `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;`

For achieve it, also need to use following piece of *(method's)* code. This method will return correct date of specific selected day, you just need to pass **day** as parameter of method such like,

> If selected day is **sunday** then pass **1**
>      If selected day is **monday** then pass **2**
>      .
>      .
>      .
>      If selected day is **saturday** then pass **7**

Here is method code :

```
-(NSDate *) getDateOfSpecificDay:(NSInteger ) day /// here day will be 1 or 2.. or 7
{
  NSInteger desiredWeekday = day
  NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit];
  NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
  NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
  NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
  NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
  return resultDate;
}
```

And don't forget to set `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but i need little more help regarding answer no: 2. is it possible to get some sample code about how to use your answer with date picker config? i am not quite sure where i have to implement this :( thank you very much again @iPatel

Comment: After spending couple of hour to understand your method then i implement it and now it worked perfectly ! Thank you @iPatel.

Comment: @Rick Why when i installed fireDate 7-Sunday my notification appear every day on current time, but i set 7-Sunday, already tried 4 examples with the same code but no one good solution, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's @iPatel's solution that also factors in the time component passed in via the datepicker. (I also updated his solution to use the latest calendar units that aren't deprecated).

```
- (NSDate *) getFireDateForDayOfWeek:(NSInteger)desiredWeekday withTime:(NSDate *)time // 1:Sunday - 7:Saturday
{
    NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;

    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
    NSDate *fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:     NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:time];
    NSDateComponents *fireDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                components: NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond
                fromDate:fireDate];

    fireDateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour;
    fireDateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute;
    fireDateComponents.second = 0;

    NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:fireDateComponents];

    // The day could be today but time is in past. If so, move ahead to next week
    if(resultDate.timeIntervalSinceNow < 0) {
        resultDate = [resultDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 7];
    }

    return resultDate;
}
```

Comment: Oren, How are you? for the last couple hours im trying to understand your code , it's exactly what i need but it doesn't seems to work. Please contact me as fast as you can , I been working on something for 3 days and still haven't figure this simple part lol. Toda Ahi :) muliastudios@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This solution also takes time in account but it's a bit more simplified than Oren's

```
-(NSDate *) dateOfSpecificDay:(NSInteger ) day withFireTime:(NSDate *)timeDate/// here day will be 1 or 2.. or 7 and timeDate the current day with the desired time 
{
    NSInteger desiredWeekday = day;
    NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
    if (differenceDays == 0) {
        //Check if should register for same day or for next week
        if ([timeDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            //Should schedule for next week
            differenceDays = daysInWeek;
        }
    }

    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
    NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:timeDate options:0];

    return resultDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ***swift*** version:

```
func calculateTheNExtFriday(inputTime: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let desiredWeekday = 6 // Friday

    let weekDateRange = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().maximumRangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday)
    let daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    let currentWeekday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, fromDate: inputTime).weekday
    let differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek

    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = differenceDays

    let calculatedFridayDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: inputTime, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    return calculatedFridayDate!
}
```

In this example, I use the desiredWeekday inside the function but you can use it as parameter as well.

> NB: Keep in mind that the day 1 corresponds to Sunday, 2 -> Monday and
>   so on

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
func calculateSpecificDay(_ desiredWeekday: NSInteger, fromDate: Date = Date()) -> Date {

    let weekDateRange = NSCalendar.current.maximumRange(of: .weekday)!
    let daysInWeek = weekDateRange.lowerBound.distance(to: weekDateRange.upperBound) - weekDateRange.lowerBound + 1

    let currentWeekday = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: fromDate).weekday
    let differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday! + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = differenceDays

    let calculatedFridayDate = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: fromDate)
    return calculatedFridayDate!
}
```

> ```
> If selected day is sunday then pass 1
> If selected day is monday then pass 2
> .
> .
> .
> If selected day is saturday then pass 7
> ```