# developing alarm repeating days list

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to make a repeat list like in the picture below for my alarm app in swift, I've tried my best but all my attempts have failed, how I can do it, how I can save multiple values in one attributes in database, do I need array, how i can do check list; my project is almost complete, the only thing left is repeat list which I failed to make it

thanks in advance

**Reminder.swift**

```
verride func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


       if segue.identifier == "presentDay" {

            if let daysPickerVie

wController = segue.destinationViewController as? Days {
            let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            detailLabel.text = daysPickerViewController.days[(path?.row)!]
        }
    }
}
```

**Days.swift**

```
class Days: UITableViewController
{
    var lastSelectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

    let days = [
        "Everyday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday"]


     var selectedDay:String?
     var selectedDayIndex:Int?
     var cell:UITableViewCell?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
      //navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Back"
    }

extension Days{


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
        }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daySelected", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


    cell.accessoryType = .None
    cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.row]
    selectedDay = days[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }
}

extension Days {


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                if cell.selected {
                    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                }
              }

        }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                cell.accessoryType = .None
            }


        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please comment the code what you tried

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481987/repeat-uilocalnotification-on-specific-day

Comment: @ Ramkumar chintala I've added the code

Comment: @MonikaSaini among of all these complexities what you've given me is the only thing I can do, but thanks :)

Comment: Did you solve it? Im trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I think the most appropriate method here is the good old bit mask. Recognizing that bitwise operations are difficult for many people[1] please find below a solution that works without bitwise operators. The attribute can be of type `Int` and it can capture all possible variations with the following logic:

```
0        no days selected
1        Sundays selected
2        Mondays selected
4        Tuesdays selected
8        Wednesdays selected
// etc...
```

The value to be stored is the sum of all selections, so e.g. for every Monday and Friday it would be `2 + 32 = 34`.

You can write an elegant `struct` to handle the conversion from the raw value to the list of selected days.

[1] *There are 10 kinds of people in the world. Those that understand binary numbers and those that don't.*

Comment: two more extra questions, do I need switch for this process, for example `case: 6` for Monday and Tuesday or `case 5` Sunday or Tuesday, but it will take a long list to cover all possibilities; the second question when i try to pass the selected day to the alarm view, I fail, I know I shall use `prepareForSegue` function, but the only value is returned from repeat list is `everyday` even if I selected different days, how this can be solved

Comment: These are really different problems. You should ask them by opening new questions. -- Short answer: No, switch is not appropriate in this case. If you do not understand the arithmetic of this setup, perhaps you are over your head with this. -- This is data structure question is independent of any UIKit problems you might have.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, thats a great approach for saving. Thanks User your code saved me some time. Im posting an answer on the parsing the data question for future reference

Answer (score 0):

I was having same Problem but solve it.There is no need of "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" method. Update your code like below:

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let day = days[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = day
    if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

          return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if self.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: self.selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath)!)
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    else {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        self.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for User question about Mundi Answer
for future reference: You don't need a switch. Just parse the data as binary: so For example 
3 in binary is 11 -> the first one is in the 2s case and the second in the 1s case. So it the last digit of the binary number is 1 then Sunday is selected. If the second from right is 1 then Tuesday is selected and so on.

**Example**

```
14
In binary: 1110
1st case from right is 0 -> Sunday is not selected
2nd case from right is 1 -> Monday is selected
3rd case from right is 1 -> Tuesday is selected
4th case from right is 1 -> Wednesday is selected
There are no more cases so no other day is selected
```